# Accessing React Function in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have :

```
addW () {
    code
    code
}

render () {

  return (
      html code
      html code
      <button onClick={this.addW}>Add</button>
  )
}
```

For some reason, I get an error :

this.addW is not a function.  Why is it not finding the function above?

TY!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a `""`

`return "<button onClick={this.addW}>Add</button>"`

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that I need to '.bind(this)'

```
<button onClick={this.addW.bind(this)}>Add</button>
```

It would help for someone to help explain this.